# Updating wpf parent window after some action on another window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

i have one wpf window called usermanagement and there is a listbox showing all the users, i have one button in usermanagement window called add user and when i click on that new window opens called adduser, in this window there are input fields to add new user, what i need when i save data and this adduser window close then the usermanagement window update the listbox, means users again update (the new added user should show there after adding). at the moment i needed to open the usermanagement window again to see the new added user. Thanks!

here is the code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections;
using Model;

namespace Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for frmUserManagement.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class frmUserManagement : Window 
    {
        public frmUserManagement()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void window_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            load_users();
        }
        public void load_users()
        {
            RST_DBDataContext conn = new RST_DBDataContext();
            var users = (from s in conn.TblUsers
                         select s.UserName).ToList();
            Login_Names.ItemsSource = users;
        }
        private void add_user(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            adduser AddUserWindow = new adduser();
            AddUserWindow.ShowDialog();
        }


    }
}
```

in xaml file there is

```
<Grid>
        <ListBox Name="Login_Names" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="337" Margin="10,47,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156">
<Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,404,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="add_user"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You should post your code .
Are you using an ObservableCollection<User> ?

Comment: hi @eranotzap i editted the question with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do insert operations inside main window (UserManagmentWindow):

UserManagmentWindow.cs:

```
 // Inside add button handler open adduser window as dialog box...
 var result = adduser.ShowDialog();
 if(result == true){
     // user pressed OK button...
     // insert new user in database
     // refresh UserManagmentWindow
 }
```

Post your code if you need more details...

Comment: i have done with your code but, with little modification, i declared another variable in adduser window and after saving data i return that true and then i use if condition in usermanagement and that worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an event in Your AddUser window, and trigger the event when you press the button.

First define your EventArgs child class

```
public class AddUserEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public User AddInfo { get; private set; }

    public AddUserEventArgs(User info)
    {
        this.AddInfo = info;
    }
}
```

In your AddUser class:

```
public event EventHandler<AddUserEventArgs> AddedUser;

private void Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs)
{
    User info = new User();
    // Realize your validation here...

    // If validation is Okay, then..
    if (OK)
    {
        if (this.AddedUser != null)
            this.AddedUser(this, new AddUserEventArgs(info));
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

In your UserManagement class:

```
var window = new AddUserWindow();
window.AddedUser += (sender, e) => 
{
    // Add the info to your ObservableCollection.
    this.collection.Add(e.AddInfo);
}
window.ShowDialog();
```